# Finding non latin characters in a table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

The table I'm working with "lives" in an Oracle database (mind my poor english).

The query I'm using is:

```
select * from table_name
where field_name not like '%[a-z]%'
```

I've also tried:

```
select * from table_name
where field_name not like '%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try a negative `like` instead of `not like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE field_name LIKE '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
```

The `^` denotes the negative.

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions.

Comment: That's plain wrong. I don't understand why this was accepted as a "working answer"

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `REGEXP_LIKE`

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( COLUMN_NAME, '[^A-Za-z0-9/\\-?:().,''+ ]' );
```

or:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(
         COLUMN_NAME,
         '[^'                            -- Match any character that is not:
         || CHR(9)                       -- Horizontal Tab
         || CHR(10)                      -- Line Feed
         || CHR(13)                      -- Carriage Return
         || CHR(32) || '-' || CHR(126)   -- All characters from Space to Tilde
         || ']'
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

The queries you so kindly provided wouldn't work because it didn't use regex.

So what I have to do to achieve my goal is:

1. `select column_name from table_name`
2. Copy the results to a notepad++ window
3. Execute `Find` command with the following in "Find what" field: `[^A-za-z0-9/\\-?:().,'+ ]`, select "regular expression"

and it indeed returns the fields with non-latin characters.